# PHP echo array?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input, foreach

Im new at this and not sure how to fill an array and echo it. Can someone please help me? :)

First my array, that I hope is retrieving info from my notes.txt-file, if there is any?! Im not sure if i need both declarations?:

```
$test = array();
$test[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), TRUE);
```

Anyway, this is the code for adding elements to the array, the input from the user:

```
$name = guestbook_input($_POST['name']);
$comment = guestbook_input($_POST['comment']);

$test[] = [
    'name' => $name,
    'comment' => $comment,
    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'time' => date("y-m-d H:m")
];

// Write input to file
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($test));
```

This code works fine (I think) and writes to the file.

Finally Im trying to echo the array to a table like this:

```
<?php
$getfile = json_decode(file_get_contents('./notes.txt'), TRUE);
        foreach ($getfile as $value):   ?>
        <tr>
            <?php
                echo '<td>';
                echo $value['name'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $value['comment'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>IP:';
                echo $value['ip'];
                echo "<br>Tid:";
                echo $value['time'];
                echo '</td>'?>

        </tr>  <?php    endforeach; ?>
```

This code do print elements, but only for the first input in my guestbook. I have no idea if this is the right way to do this or not, but hopefully someone can help me with this, so I can get this right?!

Comment: take a look at file_put_contents and the 3rd paramenter FILE_APPEND ...

Comment: show us print_r($getfile) in your question,

Comment: I don't have a print_r($getfile). Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: what you got in notes.txt file? would you please update it with your question

Comment: In your [`date`](http://si1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, you should use `i` for minutes. `m` is for months.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, your declaration and assignment:

```
$test = array();
$test[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), TRUE);
```

The function `json_decode()`, as you're calling it, returns an array, so it is not *necessary* to declare the variable first, but it is good practice to do so. However, in the function call, you are actually assigning the entire results to `$test[0]`, since `$test[]` simply creates a new element with the next numeric index. The code where you assign the user input is correct, so it gets output correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You are putting your array that you read from a file into a single element of the array `$test`.
Then you are adding your new entry as the second element.

You should initialise the array as:

```
$test = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), TRUE);
```